# Combine two Binary Search Trees

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have two `Binary Search Trees (t1,t2)` every node in `t1` is smaller than every node in `t2`. I want a function `f(t1,t2)` to create a new binary tree containing both. Execution time must be `O(max (h1,h2)`).
Any ideas?

Comment: We won't do your homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I thought to apply In order Traversal for each Tree and then insert the nodes I come up with into the final tree , but this method i am afraid does NOT comply with the execution time parameter...

void InOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> *t)

{// Inorder traversal of *t.
if (t) {InOrder(t->LeftChild);
Visit(t); InOrder(t->RightChild); }
}

Comment: I guess, that this is not what you have tried... it is just a general infix ordered traversal through a binary tree... what is your idea to solve your problem.

Comment: Is this approach correct or not??

Comment: Google: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-balanced-binary-search-trees/